# PHP: is there an instance of class in use?

Tags: php, class

I've caused a circular loop between a class and it's parent class.

The only way I can think of to fix the problem is to test if there are instances of the child class in use. Is there anyway to test for that?

So I took a break and came back the issue. The loop was caused by the __construct method in a class that deals with routing input to the appropriate logic. This class is then inherited by other classes so that if I need to do something automatically that would normally be done by the user I can implement it easily.

What I didn't see happening was that each time a child class was called, this constructor was activated to reroute the user to the right code. Since the input was identical, it was sent back to child class, setting up the loop. I have solved the issue by taking out the constructor and calling the methods needed in the site index instead, so that child classes, no longer attempt to call themselves.

Comment: Can you put some code in order to not speculate please ?

Comment: Perhaps a static member var in the childclass that gets set to true the first time it's ever instantiated? Basically `static $instantiated=false;` in the class, then set that to true in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should adjust your code to avoid the loop. It sounds like a bad thing what you did and it's likely to cause troubles in the future. So my suggestion is to redesign your code so you avoid the loop instead of fixing it.

Comment: ^^ added fix details to question

Answer (score 0):

You could use [instanceof](http://uk.php.net/instanceof) to check if it's an instance of a class. Or [is_subclass_of](https://www.php.net/is_subclass_of) to check if it extends a class.
If you post your code maybe someone can suggest a better design, the loop can probably be avoided.